# Fundamental group of a complete intersection in real projective spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, real-algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to understand the fundamental group of the following complete intersection in $RP^2 \times RP^2 \times RP^1$:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&t_1 \left( x_1^3 + x_2^3 + x_3^3 +  a x_1 x_2 x_3 \right) +  c t_2 (x_1 x_2 x_3) = 0 \\
&&t_2 \left( y_1^3 + y_2^3 + y_3^3 +  b y_1 y_2 y_3 \right) +  c t_1 (y_1 y_2 y_3) = 0
\end{eqnarray} 
where $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are the coordinates of one $RP^2$, $y_1,y_2,y_3$ are the coordinates of the other $RP^2$ and $t_1,t_2$ are the coordinates of $RP^1$.  Also $a,b,c$ are real parameters.

I would also be interested in the fundamental group for special choices of the parameters, in case it is easier.

So far I have not been able to find any reference which helps me tackle this problem, so this would also be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you write hypersurface?  It looks like your two equations are independent, and the locus they describe has codimension 2.